# How do I find if a list is a member of a list of lists?

Tags: prolog

I am quite new to prolog so I am a bit confused on the pattern-matching. What I'd like to do is if List A is [1,2] and List B is [*,[1,2],*] it returns true, otherwise false.

Currently I have:

```
isNotMember([X],[]).
isNotMember([X],[Y|Rest]) :- not isEqual([X],[Y]), isNotMember([X],Rest).

isEqual([],[]).
isEqual([X|Rest],[Y|Rest]) :- X = Y, isEqual(Rest,Rest).
```

The isEqual predicate works but the isNotMember predicate does not, which I believe is due to pattern matching. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This works in Prolog: `?- A = [1,2], B = [1,2], A = B.`. You don't need to test every member. Prolog does this kind of structure binding for you.

Comment: You can even do it with variables: `?- A = [1,2], B = [1,X], A = B, write(X).` That writes out `2`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, are you saying that `B` is a list that contains the list as an element? In that case, this works: `?- A = [1, 2], B = [q, [1, X], 4, 'hello'], member(A, B), write(X).`.

Comment: You can just use `member`. Why would you need another predicate?